# systemd --user: Increase Max open files

Tags: systemd

I have a problem with systemd on OpenSuSE 15.1. I'm trying to run a java-based application server which always gives me the Error "Too many open files!" I've worked through several tutorials now and what I've set so far is:

In `/etc/systemd/user.conf` and /`etc/systemd/system.conf`
`DefaultLimitNOFILE=200000`

`ulimit -n` gives 65535

```
systemctl --user show | grep LimitNOFILE and systemctl show | grep LimitNOFILE 

DefaultLimitNOFILE=200000
DefaultLimitNOFILESoft=200000
```

However, if I try to access the process directly: `cat /proc/<pid>/limits`, I can see a line:

`Max open files            **4096**                 4096                 files`

If I access the service directly: `systemctl --user show <someservice>.service | grep LimitNOFILE`

I still get: `LimitNOFILE=65535`

I have absolutely no idea anymore on what could limit the NOFILE to 4096. The service itself is started via --user, and none of the configuration file changes had any effect.

Also, the `.service` file, upon creation, has a line `LimitNOFILE=100000`.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you identified for how many open files do you get "too many open files" error?